# наследование ошибка Python

Tags: python

Почему выдает ошибку?

```
from restaurant import Restaurant
class Ice_Cream_Stand(Restaurant):
    """Потомок класса ресторан"""
    def __init__(self,restaurant_name, cuisine_name):
        super.__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_name)
        # Создаем специфичный атрибут для класса мороженное
        self.flavors = []

    def print_flavors(self):
        """выводим список мороженого"""
        print(f"В наличие следующие виды мороженого {self.flavors}")

ice = Ice_Cream_Stand('Bobo', 'ice_cream')
ice.flavors = ['asf', 'asga', 'fhnh']
ice.print_flavors()
```

Сама ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pythonProject\9\ice_cream_stand.py", line 13, in <module>
    ice = Ice_Cream_Stand('Bobo', 'ice_cream')
  File "C:\pythonProject\9\ice_cream_stand.py", line 5, in __init__
    super.__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_name)
TypeError: descriptor '__init__' requires a 'super' object but received a 'str'
```

Comment: Потому что вы забыли написать скобочки после `super()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скобок не хватает:

```
super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_name)
#    ^^--- этих
```

Comment: спасибо, понял))))